# UIView setFrame problem

Tags: ipad, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I must do something wrong, but dont know what..

I try to add a subView with this code:

```
subMenuView = [[UISubMenuViewMainController alloc] init];

[subMenuView.view setFrame:CGRectMake(10,0,990,100)];

subMenuView.view.backgroundColor  = [UIColor whiteColor];

[self.view addSubview:subMenuView.view];
```

I want my view to be at (10,0) and have 990/100 in width/height

but i dont get the expected result

Let me if I m wrong, If I want a 10x10 square view at the center i have to add the following line:

```
[subMenuView.view setFrame:CGRectMake(512,384,10,10)];
```

That s not what I get, the position is correct, but the width/height are wrong, any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18850871/cgrectmake-is-not-working-with-uiview

Answer (score 7, accepted):

problem fixed by setting

```
self.view.autoresizesSubviews = NO;
```

Answer (score 11):

if you use autolayout,the call setFrame have no use,try call  setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints before setFrame

Comment: set to YES or NO ? It's better to provide example

Comment: You should mention what it should be set to.

Answer (score 0):

The code is a little unconventional, but I'll hazard a guess it's because you are setting the view's frame before you add it as a subview.  Hence the subview's position probably gets changed by layoutSubviews before you see it.

So try putting the second line of code last and see if that does the trick.

Comment: I get exactly the same problem with setFrame and the end of the code snippet

Comment: I dont undestand because I m adding a lot of other controls (UIButton) with this method before and all works perfect.

Answer (score -1):

Try using floats instead of ints:

```
[subMenuView.view setFrame:CGRectMake(10,0,990,100)];
```

to:

```
[subMenuView.view setFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f,0.0f,990.0f,100.0f)];
```

Comment: same problem, I think GCC can cast my int to float at compile time withtout any problem