# CGRectMake is not working with UIView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview

I spent hours of my day today just to hide PickerView when my app is loaded, but the problem is not with the PickerView. it's with CGRectMake.

I tried a simple project on Xcode just to show you that CGRectMake doesn't work for me...

here's my storyboard (grey area is UIView component) :

[image]

and here's my interface :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *container;

@end
```

and here's my implementation file :

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    _container.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 204);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

it's very basic code, not contaminated with other codes... but still, any numbers given to that CGRectMake doesn't make that grey area move. I've changed X, Y value, but the grey UIView stand still just like what you see on storyboard.

why CGRectMake is not working on my case? where's the problem?

UPDATE : I see autolayout is checked on my inspector box

[image]

UPDATE : here's my Connection inspector

[image]

Comment: Do you have AutoLayout enabled in the Storyboard?

Comment: Yes I did, please check my update. is that what you mean?

Comment: CGRectMake is working. I'm sure it set the frame correctly. However for the UIView not to react it probably means some layout is taking place at later time (probably auto layout?). Try overriding layoutSubviews and do nothing inside.

Comment: Yes, rule 1 of AutoLayout. You can't change the frame of any views. You have constraints that are holding the view in place. You can try to change the frame but it won't work because the constraints are holding it in place. You can either turn off AutoLayout or update the constraints instead of using `_container.frame = ...`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have `AutoLayout` enabled for the `Storyboard` then changing the `frame` of a view won't work.

You can't change frames directly using `AutoLayout`. You have to change the constraints around them.

If you disable `AutoLayout` for the `Storyboard` it will work.

Comment: you're a brilliant man!!! you solve this problem!!! many thanks from me... I LOVE YOU, MAN!!! ;-)

Comment: The "real" solution though is to get the behaviour you want WITH AutoLayout :) http://www.raywenderlich.com/store/ios-6-by-tutorials This book is awesome. I learnt all the AutoLayout stuff from it.

Answer (score 1):

> Make sure that your `IBOUTLET` connection is joined with the view.

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply... I just update my post. Added my connection inspector. is it what cause the problem?

Answer (score 1):

CGrectmake working only because you set frame size as CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 204); as per the size the custom view will be visible inside the main view if you want to hide change x or y co-ordinates to out of bound value like this. Then don forget to uncheck autolayout

```
container.frame = CGRectMake(200, 0, 320, 204);
```

Comment: I found the problem, bro... it's all because of 'AutoLayout'... thanks for coming here...

Comment: ya k.. now hope picker hiding

Comment: yes it is... I spent more than 12 hours just to find this... nice to see you... ;-)

Comment: You can simply set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES; on the uiView element and still keep your autolayout. This will redraw the element to new frame.