# Dynamically & programmatically resize UIView in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I am displaying a list of users and their respective badges they have won, so each user has three different counts (gold, silver, bronze).  In addition to displaying the # of badges they've earned, I want to have a rectangle in the background that is resized depending on how many badges they have (kind of like a bar chart).

This is how I am attempting to do it so far. (I have a UIView called goldRect in my storyboard, with a height of 20 and width of only 1 pixel to start.) Then I do:

```
cell.goldRect.frame = CGRectMake(cell.goldRect.frame.origin.x, cell.goldRect.frame.origin.y, 28*numGolds, cell.goldRect.frame.size.height);
```

But nothing changes, the bar still remains at width one pixel.  Any help?

Comment: Animations!! or try this SO post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18850871/cgrectmake-is-not-working-with-uiview?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Are you want to change the width or height? Suppose you want to change the width you mentioned only 28*numGolds not all badges, you mention all badges count here. 28*allBadgesCount.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
cell.goldRect.frame = CGRectMake(cell.goldRect.frame.origin.x, cell.goldRect.frame.origin.y, 28*numGolds, 20);
```

In your case, you not change gold rect height, because you set it to cell.goldRect.frame.size.height. The same what it was.

Comment: Hm, didn't change it... I think it has something to do with my constraints as well